# HP Printer does not print from primary account, Windows 7 64=bit

Tags: printing, printer

I have an HP Deskjet Printer. At first everything was OK, but recently it has stopped printing.

My problem started after pressing on the "Print". the Queue icon in the notification bar shows me 0 documents pending. This doesn't happen when I print a page from a web browser, it just happens with programs like Microsoft Word and Adobe Reader.

I have made another Windows account, and when I tried to print from Adobe Reader there was no problem! I am using Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Set your printer to default. or goto print properties and make sure your printer is the printer you want to print from, assuming you installed some other program and it changed the default printer.

Comment: It is the default, and I made sure that is the printer I want to print from, but always "0 document pendings"

Comment: try re-installing your printer software/drivers

Comment: I did it alot of times with the same result

Comment: not sure, just create a new account and move everything over, it will take less time to do that then to figure out what your problem is.